# text-overflow:ellipsis doesn't work on in Table cell hyper links

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone please help me in below issue.
I have a table with some hyper links in once cell. I want to show 3 dots when the text exceeds to cell width. Basically I want to display only one link per line and if there is a long text in hyper link, it should not spill over to next line.
Browser: IE

```
.foi_overlap_ink {
text-overflow: ellipsis;
word-break: keep-all;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

```css
.foi_overlap_ink {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    word-break: keep-all;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.firstColumn {
    text-align: left;
    width: 150px;
}

.secondColumn {
    text-align: left;
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    
<TD class=firstColumn style="BORDER-TOP: #8f8f8f 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #8f8f8f 1px solid; BORDER-BOTTOM: #8f8f8f 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #8f8f8f 1px solid"><B>Overlap Link</B></TD>
<TD class="secondColumn foi_overlap_ink" style="BORDER-TOP: #8f8f8f 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #8f8f8f 1px solid; BORDER-BOTTOM: #8f8f8f 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #8f8f8f 1px solid">
<A style="OVERFLOW: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 12px; TEXT-DECORATION: underline; TEXT-OVERFLOW: ellipsis; COLOR: blue" href="javascript:repoTableDefaultDetails('123123123','2013-03-31','2016-10-05');">2013-03-31-2015 - bonappetit Condensat</A> 

<BR><A style="FONT-SIZE: 12px; TEXT-DECORATION: underline; COLOR: blue" href="javascript:repoTableDefaultDetails('123123123','2013-04-30','2016-03-07');">2013-04-30-DailyExcerise</A> 

<BR><A style="FONT-SIZE: 12px; TEXT-DECORATION: underline; COLOR: blue" href="javascript:repoTableDefaultDetails('123123123','2013-10-31','2016-03-07');">2013-04-30-DailyExcerise</A> 

<BR><A style="FONT-SIZE: 12px; TEXT-DECORATION: underline; COLOR: blue" href="javascript:repoTableDefaultDetails('123123123','2014-03-31','2016-03-07');">2013-04-30-DailyExcerise</A> 

<BR><A style="FONT-SIZE: 12px; TEXT-DECORATION: underline; COLOR: blue" href="javascript:repoTableDefaultDetails('123123123','2014-05-31','2016-03-07');">2013-04-30-DailyExcerise</A> 

<BR><A style="FONT-SIZE: 12px; TEXT-DECORATION: underline; COLOR: blue" href="javascript:repoTableDefaultDetails('123123123','2014-06-30','2016-03-07');">2013-04-30-DailyExcerise</A> 

<BR><A style="FONT-SIZE: 12px; TEXT-DECORATION: underline; COLOR: blue" href="javascript:repoTableDefaultDetails('123123123','2013-03-31','2016-03-07');">2013-04-30-DailyExcerise</A>

</TD>
</tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: see if this helps https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531174(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
.secondColumn {
    text-align: left;
    width: 50px;
    display: block;
}
```

Add display block to the class secondColumn. this makes it a block element and takes the specified width and your ellipsis works.

Comment: You are correct. But it looks like I must have to mention table-layout: fixed, Which I can't. So for me it is still an issue.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, wrap the contents of each cell in a div, and style that div instead. It would require some formatting on your table too, however.

Here's a demo:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid;
  max-width: 65px;
}

div {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>title 1</th>
    <th>title 2</th>
    <th>title 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>text</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>text text</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>text text text</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example, Looks like I must have to mention table-layout: fixed, Which I can't. So for me it is still an issue.

Comment: I see. Since you didn't specify that in your question, I'll leave this answer here for any potential future readers with similar issues, but who can use `fixed`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`text-overflow` only applies to `block` containers: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#text-overflow

`a` is not a `block` container: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2

Simply make it a block with `display: block;`

Note that you'll also have to keep the table column narrow enough to have the ellipsis (`max-width: 50px;` instead of `width:50px;`)

Answer (score 0):

I would write:

```
.secondColumn {
text-align: left;
/* width: 50px;*/
width: 150px;/* according to your given example*/
max-width: 150px;
```

}